# Using containers with non-EF types in OData service?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, odata

We are trying to add a list of strings to our OData service using ReflectionProvider:

```
[DataServiceKey("ID")]
Public class Project
        public IEnumerable<Picture> Images { get; set; }
        // Picture is an EF entity and everything works
        public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }
        // Same situation here, only strings -- service fails to start!
}
```

Are we missing something? 
We can create a new entity in Entity Framework to contain only a string property, but this seems to be an overkill for just storing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections of primitive values (for example strings) is a feature only supported in OData V3 and in WCF DS it was implemented in the recently release WCF DS 5.0 (https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services or the installable http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/09/wcf-data-services-5-0-rtm-release.aspx).

Currently the collection properties are only supported in the reflection provider. EF doesn't support them yet. (It's unclear from you question whether you use reflection or EF since you mention both).